# Page Opening after multiple refreshing

Tags: webserver, web

I recently changed my dedicated server from hosthaat.com to codero.com

The problem that I am facing is, whenever any user tries to open any webpage on the server it does not open in one go. It gives a network error and when the page is refreshed multiple times only then does it open.

Some sites on the server :

```
www.raajneeti.org
www.fanshala.com
www.advocateguru.com
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Those work for me without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sites opens normally.

This is most probably an end user network problem - they just have unstable internet connection. You can use free web services like loadimpact.com to simulate multiple users from different countries accessing your site and see the effect for yourself.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. This is not a problem faced by an individual, but most of the users. Pages require multiple refresh to open and are very slow. All the other sites(not on this server) are opening normally. Please suggest.